# Saving data from Snowflake to S3 bucket as a XLSX file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wan't to save query result from Snowflake. I can save the file as a CSV file but is it possible to save the data as an XLSX file

The query I used:

```
file_name = 'w{}_processedsample_{}_rawsample.xlsx'.format(wave_number, time_stamp)
    
query = f"select * from {database}.{schema}.{view} where wavenumber={wave_number}"
    
get_view_query = f"copy into  @{database}.{schema}.{save_to_s3_stage}/{file_name} from ({query})  HEADER = TRUE OVERWRITE = TRUE SINGLE=TRUE FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' NULL_IF ='' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\\\\' EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE ENCODING = UTF8)"
```

Currently the xlsx file is corrupt. Also I need the xlsx file to not be zipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you unload data from Snowflake you can only save it to one of the [supported file formats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-prepare.html#supported-file-formats):

[image]

You can't change the file extension to anything you like. In your example, you are unloading a CSV file that is simply named with a `.xlsx` extension so your computer doesn't open it properly with excel (probably because it's compressed actually).

To make sure the file is not zipped, change your file format to (the last line is the change):

```
FILE_FORMAT = (
   TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
   NULL_IF ='' 
   ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\\\\' 
   EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE 
   ENCODING = UTF8
   COMPRESSION= NONE
)"
```

Comment: So unloading the data as a XLSX file is not possible...Ok I will look for some other ways to do it.

Comment: That's right. Why not download as csv and just open it in Excel?

Comment: I need to unload the data into a S3 bucket as an XLSX file because another system interacts with that bucket and for some odd reason their system expects an XLSX file instead of a csv file.

Comment: Then your best bet is probably to use Pandas and use a dataframe to excel function.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I already have a function that does the conversion and data upload. I just wanted to know if I could avoid this step or not.

Comment: Snowflake presently supports 3rd party python modules in UDF and Stored procedures, the feature was released this year in June. Is it possible to use Pandas to export the data frame in XLSX format?

df.to_pandas().to_excel('outputfile.xlsx')